# ERROR: mdb_txn_renew: MDB_BAD_RSLOT: Invalid reuse of reader locktable slot

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, lmdb

I'm hoping someone can answer my question regarding this error. I'm trying to run a notebook from this github repo and looking to test the code using my dataset.

Reference: https://colab.research.google.com/github/qwertyforce/image_search/blob/main/phash_new.ipynb

I'm running to the following error: **BadRslotError: mdb_txn_renew: MDB_BAD_RSLOT: Invalid reuse of reader locktable slot**

It's being cause my this snipet below:

`DB = lmdb.open('./phashes.lmdb',map_size=500*1_000_000) #500mb IMAGE_PATH = "./scenery"`

`def check_if_exists_by_id(id): with DB.begin(buffers=True) as txn: x = txn.get(int_to_bytes(id),default=False) if x: return True return False`

I've been trying to look on different forums but none of them seem to have the exact issue I am having. I want to say it has something to do with the documentation being updated and puzzled on where to look.